# Method delegation to the parent in case of implementing proxies in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, proxy-pattern

In an example from **Node.js Design patterns**

```
  function createProxy(subject) {
     var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(subject);
     function Proxy(subject) {
       this.subject = subject;
     }
     Proxy.prototype = Object.create(proto);
     //proxied method
     Proxy.prototype.hello = function() {
       return this.subject.hello() + ' world!';
     }
     //delegated method
     Proxy.prototype.goodbye = function() {
       return this.subject.goodbye
         .apply(this.subject, arguments);
}
     return new Proxy(subject);
   }
```

What is the need for the method delegation i.e. to redefine the **Proxy.prototype.goodbye** method again when the method from original Object will be automatically be called as the prototype chain has been set i.e.  **Proxy.prototype = Object.create(proto)**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newly instantiated `Proxy` does not inherit from the `subject` - the properties directly on `subject`'s are only available on the proxy's *subject* property. Only the *prototype* methods of the `subject` are available immediately on the Proxy object itself. So, in the case that `goodbye` is a property directly on the instantiated object, you wouldn't be able to access it directly were the `Proxy.prototype.goodbye = ...` line not there:

```js
function createProxy(subject) {
  var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(subject);
  function Proxy(subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
  }
  Proxy.prototype = Object.create(proto);
  //proxied method
  Proxy.prototype.hello = function() {
    return this.subject.hello() + ' world!';
  }
  return new Proxy(subject);
}
const prox = createProxy({
  goodbye() {
    console.log('goodbye.')
  }
});
prox.goodbye();
```

Those methods are available through the instantiated proxy's `.subject`, but not through the proxy itself, *unless you explicitly assign to* `Proxy.prototype.goodbye` as in the original code.

Comment: But *why* does it inherit from the subject's prototype? That makes no sense, given that the proxy doesn't have any instance properties.

Answer (score 2):

This code does not make any sense. There's no reason to involve inheritance here - as you noticed it makes everything confusing.

It should be simplified to

```
function createProxy(subject) {
  return {
    // proxied method
    hello() {
      return subject.hello() + ' world!';
    },
    // delegated method
    goodbye() {
      return subject.goodbye.apply(subject, arguments);
    }
  };
}
```

Or if one wanted to use a prototype object to share the methods, then

```
function Proxy(subject) {
  this.subject = subject;
}
// proxied method
Proxy.prototype.hello = function() {
  return this.subject.hello() + ' world!';
};
// delegated method
Proxy.prototype.goodbye = function() {
  return this.subject.goodbye.apply(this.subject, arguments);
};

function createProxy(subject) {
  return new Proxy(subject);
}
```

---

Maybe they wanted to anticipate using prototype inheritance to achieve implicit delegation of *all* (non-overwritten) methods, which would look like this:

```
function createProxy(subject) {
  var proxy = Object.create(subject);
  // proxied method
  proxy.hello = function() {
    return subject.hello() + ' world!';
  }
  // 'goodbye' and everything else on the subject is delegated
  return proxy;
}
```